# AngularJS Material - Disable scroll of both md-sidenav and md-content

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-material

I'm building a site with AngularJs Material sidenav.
I'd like both md-sidenav and md-content to be as 1 page, without having scrollers appear when the content of one of the elements has more height than the other. How can this be achieved? Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="content" layout="column" style="height: 100%;">
    <section layout="row" flex>
    <md-sidenav
        class="md-sidenav-left"
        md-component-id="left"
        md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-md')"
        md-whiteframe="4">

        <md-toolbar class="md-theme-indigo">
            <h1 class="md-toolbar-tools">Sidenav Left</h1>
        </md-toolbar>
        <md-content layout-padding ng-controller="LeftCtrl">
            <p hide show-gt-md>
                <p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p>
            </p>
        </md-content>
    </md-sidenav>


    <md-content flex layout-padding style="overflow: unset;">

    <div layout="column" layout-align="top center" style="height: 100%;">
        <p>The left sidenav will 'lock open' on a medium (>=960px wide) device.</p>

        <div>
            <md-button ng-click="toggleLeft()"
                class="md-primary" hide-gt-md>
                Toggle left
            </md-button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div flex></div>
    </md-content>
    </section>
</div> <!-- end .content -->
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `position` property.

```
sidenav > md-sidenav, sidenav > md-backdrop {
    position: fixed !important;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, it didn't work. I added them directly to the index.php document within `<style>` tags, but no difference with these CSS rules applied.

Comment: Per https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/20276935 - the answer was already given before the link; please be more careful when reviewing answers in the queue.

Comment: @TylerH sorry I don't understand

Comment: @Zooly You recommended the answer for deletion as a link-only answer, but it is not link-only. The answer is given, followed by a link for more information.

Comment: Oh ok sorry for this bad review, but is it the good place to tell that? ^^